# Download the html text collected in a string builder to word document in VB.NET Console Application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-word

I have a requirement to move the html text available in a string builder to a word document and open the word document after the data is appended in a VB.NET console application. I am new to console applications and am not sure how this could be done, but I am aware that if I am using a Web Application then I can use the following code:

Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/msword")

Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=myword.doc")

Response.Write(String Builder Variable)

Can some help me with the code please....???

Answer (score 1):

Write it to a '.doc' file and use ShellExecute to call 'open' on it.

Comment: No firstly the below code is not working in the console application. It is applicable only for the web application.
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/msword")
Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=myword.doc")
Response.Write(String Builder Variable)

Comment: 1 Write the contents of the string builder to file with the suffix .doc. It should work.